# Return a flag if the cell isn't empty (multiple V lookups)

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I concatenate User ID + Date to have unique identifiers for employees on that date. The only issue is they have 4 punches which means that there is two lines of that unique ID. Below is my attempt at showing my spreadsheet (A B C) are columns. My issue that sometimes in column D there can be the word "vacation, sick, etc" if the person took the day off. It can be on the first line or the second line which means I can't do a standard Vlookup to flag it. What would be the best formula to use to flag if the unique identifier has time off either on the first or second line? All it would have to do is see if there is data in any column D relating to that unique identifier I think 
A________             B____             C__D 
929ID123      9AM           12PM 
929ID123      1PM           4PM     Sick

I am trying to get it to look like

A________             B___             C_D_E 
929ID123      9AM           12PM 
929ID123      1PM           4PM     Sick    flag

Comment: Is it as simple as `IF(D2<>"","flag", "")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `COUNTIFS` Formula - it counts the number of lines that meet multiple criteria (different from `COUNTIF` which only allows one criteria).

By 'Flag it' you could use Conditional Formatting or a formula in a different column, whichever works best. Both options listed below;

**Formula:**
Let's say your formula flag is in column E. In the first row of data (usually E2 if your columns have headings) paste the formula `=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $D:$D, "*")>0, "FLAG", "")`.
That formula will write FLAG in lines with that ID and any non-blank value in column D.

**Conditional Formatting**
Select all of column E, then in the Home tab under styles > Conditional Formatting select 'new rule'. Set the rule type to 'use a formula' and paste the formula `=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A1, $D:$D, "*")>0` in the formula box. Then click 'Format' and choose how flagged cells should show, e.g. a red fill or orange border. Hit ok when done and voila - any flagged cells will have that format applied to them.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. The formula does alert me when there is a flag but it shows up on each row. In my example from above, it would say flag in row 3 (col E) next to the word "sick", but it also says "flag" in row 2 (col E) where I would prefer it not. Is there anything I can add to the formula so it only says "flag" next to the word sick?

Comment: Ahh, sorry - I misunderstood, thought you wanted to flag by ID not just by column E. That's even easier, use `=IF($D2<>"", "FLAG", "")` in E2 and copy the formula down.

Comment: Conditional Formatting formula would be `=D1<>""`